# Animating an array

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

currently trying to animate an array of enemy sprites for within a game I'm producing in C# using XNA 4.0

Using this animation code

```
namespace Rotationgame
{
class Animation
{

    Texture2D texture;
    Rectangle rectangle;
    Vector2 position;
    Vector2 origin;
    Vector2 velocity;

    int currentFrame;
    int frameHeight;
    int frameWidth;

    float timer;
    float interval = 150;

    public Animation(Texture2D newTexture, Vector2 newPosition, int newFrameHeight, int newFrameWidth)
    {
        texture = newTexture;
        position = newPosition;
        frameHeight = newFrameHeight;
        frameWidth = newFrameWidth;
    }
    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        rectangle = new Rectangle(currentFrame * frameWidth, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
        origin = new Vector2(rectangle.Width / 2, rectangle.Height / 2);
        position = position + velocity;

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyUp(Keys.F1))
        {
            AnimateRight(gameTime);
            velocity.X = 0;
        }
        else if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyUp(Keys.F2))
        {
            AnimateLeft(gameTime);
            velocity.X = -0;
        }
        else velocity = Vector2.Zero;

    }

    public void AnimateRight(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 2;
        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;
            timer = 0;
            if (currentFrame > 1)
                currentFrame = 0;
        }
    }

    public void AnimateLeft(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        timer += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 2;
        if (timer > interval)
        {
            currentFrame++;
            timer = 0;
            if (currentFrame > 1)
                currentFrame = 0;
        }
    }


    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, rectangle, Color.White, 0f, origin, 1.0f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);

    }
}
}
```

And this code for the array

```
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;


    Animation[] invaders;


protected override void Initialize()
    {
       invaders = new Animation[13];

        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

  protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);



// Array of Space Invaders
        invaders[0] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(400, 400), 115, 96);
        invaders[1] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(427, 310), 115, 96);
        invaders[2] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(427, 490), 115, 96);
        invaders[3] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(490, 250), 115, 96);
        invaders[4] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(490, 550), 115, 96);
        invaders[5] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(580, 240), 115, 96);
        invaders[7] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(580, 560), 115, 96);
        invaders[8] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(670, 550), 115, 96);
        invaders[9] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(670, 250), 115, 96);
        invaders[10] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(730, 490), 115, 96);
        invaders[11] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(730, 310), 115, 96);
        invaders[12] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(757, 400), 115, 96);
     }

protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();

// Drawing Invaders
                foreach (Animation invader in invaders)
                    invaders.Draw(spriteBatch);

}

        spriteBatch.End();
```

Everything works in the code in visual Studio however I get a error on the Draw method saying: "Error   1   'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Draw' and no extension method 'Draw' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Any ideas what's gone wrong?

Edit: Here is full code of game1 file

```
namespace Rotationgame
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;


    Animation[] invaders;

    // Different Windows
    enum GameState
    {
        MainMenu,
        Playing,
    }
    GameState CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;

    // Screeb Adjustments
    int screenWidth = 1250, screenHeight = 930;

    // Main Menu Buttons
    button btnPlay;
    button btnQuit;

    // Pause Menu & buttons
    bool paused = false;
    button btnResume;
    button btnMainMenu;



    // Player's Movement
    Vector2 spriteVelocity;
    const float tangentialVelocity = 0f;
    float friction = 1f;

    Texture2D spriteTexture;
    Rectangle spriteRectangle;

    Vector2 spritePosition;
    float rotation;

    // The centre of the image
    Vector2 spriteOrigin;



    // Background
    Texture2D backgroundTexture;
    Rectangle backgroundRectangle;


    // Shield
    Texture2D shieldTexture;
    Rectangle shieldRectangle;

    // Bullets
    List<Bullets> bullets = new List<Bullets>();
    KeyboardState pastKey;



    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to perform any initialization it needs to before starting to run.
    /// This is where it can query for any required services and load any non-graphic
    /// related content.  Calling base.Initialize will enumerate through any components
    /// and initialize them as well.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
       invaders = new Animation[12];

        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here

        base.Initialize();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// LoadContent will be called once per game and is the place to load
    /// all of your content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        // Load Player's Shield (Cosmetic at moment as not set up fully
        shieldTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Shield");
        shieldRectangle = new Rectangle(517, 345, 250, 220);

        // Load Player's Ship
        spriteTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("PlayerShipright");
        spritePosition = new Vector2(640, 450);

        // Load Game background
        backgroundTexture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("Background");
        backgroundRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 1250, 930);

        // Screen Adjustments
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = screenWidth;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = screenHeight;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
        IsMouseVisible = true;


        // Main menu Buttons & locations
        btnPlay = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Playbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnPlay.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 310));

        btnQuit = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Quitbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnQuit.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 580));

        // Array of Space Invaders
        invaders[0] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(400, 400), 115, 96);
        invaders[1] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(427, 310), 115, 96);
        invaders[2] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(427, 490), 115, 96);
        invaders[3] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(490, 250), 115, 96);
        invaders[4] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(490, 550), 115, 96);
        invaders[5] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(580, 240), 115, 96);
        invaders[6] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(580, 560), 115, 96);
        invaders[7] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(670, 550), 115, 96);
        invaders[8] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(670, 250), 115, 96);
        invaders[9] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(730, 490), 115, 96);
        invaders[10] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(730, 310), 115, 96);
        invaders[11] = new Animation(Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore"), new Vector2(757, 400), 115, 96);


        // Pause menu buttons & locations
        btnResume = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Playbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnResume.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 310));

        btnMainMenu = new button(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Quitbutton"), graphics.GraphicsDevice);
        btnMainMenu.setPosition(new Vector2(550, 580));

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// UnloadContent will be called once per game and is the place to unload
    /// all content.
    /// </summary>
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the game to run logic such as updating the world,
    /// checking for collisions, gathering input, and playing audio.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();



        // Allows the game to exit
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.MainMenu:
                if(btnPlay.isClicked == true) CurrentGameState = GameState.Playing;
                btnPlay.Update(mouse);

                if (btnQuit.isClicked == true)
                    this.Exit();
                    btnQuit.Update(mouse);

                  break;

            case GameState.Playing:

                  if (!paused)
                  {
                      if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))
                      {
                          paused = true;
                          btnResume.isClicked = false;
                      }
                  }
                  else if (paused)
                  {
                      if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Enter))

                      if (btnResume.isClicked)
                          paused = false;
                      if (btnMainMenu.isClicked) CurrentGameState = GameState.MainMenu;
                  }



                break;


        }


        // TODO: Add your update logic here

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && pastKey.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
            Shoot();
        pastKey = Keyboard.GetState();

        spritePosition = spriteVelocity + spritePosition;

        spriteRectangle = new Rectangle((int)spritePosition.X, (int)spritePosition.Y,
            spriteTexture.Width, spriteTexture.Height);
        spriteOrigin = new Vector2(spriteRectangle.Width / 2, spriteRectangle.Height / 2);

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) rotation += 0.025f;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left)) rotation -= 0.025f;

        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            spriteVelocity.X = (float)Math.Cos(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;
            spriteVelocity.Y = (float)Math.Sin(rotation) * tangentialVelocity;
        }
        else if (Vector2.Zero != spriteVelocity)
        {
            float i = spriteVelocity.X;
            float j = spriteVelocity.Y;

            spriteVelocity.X = i -= friction * i;
            spriteVelocity.Y = j -= friction * j;


            base.Update(gameTime);

        }
        UpdateBullets();
    }

    public void UpdateBullets()
    {
        foreach (Bullets bullet in bullets)
        {
            bullet.position += bullet.velocity;
            if (Vector2.Distance(bullet.position, spritePosition) > 760)
                bullet.isVisible = false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < bullets.Count; i++)
        {
            if(!bullets[i].isVisible)
            {
                bullets.RemoveAt(i);
                i--;


            }


        }
    }

    public void Shoot()
    {
        Bullets newBullet = new Bullets(Content.Load<Texture2D>("bullet"));
        newBullet.velocity = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(rotation),(float)Math.Sin(rotation)) * 3f + spriteVelocity;
        newBullet.position = spritePosition + newBullet.velocity * 5;
        newBullet.isVisible = true;

        if(bullets.Count() < 25)
            bullets.Add(newBullet);
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        switch (CurrentGameState)
        {
            case GameState.MainMenu:
                spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("MainMenu"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);
                btnPlay.Draw(spriteBatch);
                btnQuit.Draw(spriteBatch);

                break;

            case GameState.Playing:
                // Drawing Background
                spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, backgroundRectangle, Color.White);

                // Drawing Shield
                spriteBatch.Draw(shieldTexture, shieldRectangle, Color.White);

                // Drawing Invaders
                foreach (Animation invader in invaders)
                    invader.Draw(spriteBatch);

                // Drawing Bullets
                foreach (Bullets bullet in bullets)
                    bullet.Draw(spriteBatch);

                // Drawing Player's Character
                spriteBatch.Draw(spriteTexture, spritePosition, null, Color.White, rotation, spriteOrigin, 1f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);



                if (paused)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("PauseMenu"), new Rectangle(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight), Color.White);
                    btnResume.Draw(spriteBatch);
                    btnMainMenu.Draw(spriteBatch);
                }

                break;






        }

        spriteBatch.End();


        // TODO: Add your drawing code here

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

2nd Edit: Button class

```
namespace Rotationgame
{
class button
{
    Texture2D texture;
    Vector2 position;
    Rectangle rectangle;

    Color colour = new Color(255, 255, 255, 255);

    public Vector2 size;

    public button(Texture2D newTexture, GraphicsDevice graphics)
    {
        texture = newTexture;

        // ScreenW = 1250 (currently atm 800), ScreenH = 930 (currently atm 600)
        //ImgW =     100 , ImgH = 20
        size = new Vector2(graphics.Viewport.Width / 8, graphics.Viewport.Height / 30);

    }
    bool down;
    public bool isClicked;
    public void Update(MouseState mouse)
    {
        rectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X,(int)position.Y,
            (int)size.X, (int)size.Y);

            Rectangle mouseRectangle = new Rectangle(mouse.X, mouse.Y, 1, 1);

        if (mouseRectangle.Intersects(rectangle))
        {
            if (colour.A == 255) down = false;
            if (colour.A == 0) down = true;
            if (down) colour.A += 3; else colour.A -= 3;
            if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed) isClicked = true;
        }
        else if (colour.A < 255)
        {
            colour.A += 3;
            isClicked = false;
        }

    }

    public void setPosition(Vector2 newPosition)
    {
        position = newPosition;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch)
    {
        spritebatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, colour);
    }
}

}
```

Comment: In your foreach loop in `Draw(GameTime)` you need to do `invader.Draw(spriteBatch)` - you have "invaders" at the moment, which is the array, yielding the error. This means that foreach `invader` in `invaders` the Draw item will be called on it.

Comment: As a side, where is `spriteBatch.End()` being called? From your code it looks like it's not in a method, and it should be at the end of your Draw method.

Comment: Oh the all the code in the 2nd window I only copied the relevant code to the array as I have too much code there, so the foreach part I copied out that part and the spriteBatch.End() part I copied out as well which explains why it looks strange there

Comment: Okay I changed the    invaders.Draw(spriteBatch); to     invader.Draw(spriteBatch); but now I get an error when actually running the game saying "NullRferenceException was unhandled" with the error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" Any ideas?

Comment: What line does the error occur on? The [NullReferanceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception.aspx) means that you are trying to perform an operation on an object that doesn't exist (i.e. that is null) - this is usually because you've forgotten to initialize it with the `new` keyword before trying to use it.

Comment: its occurring on the newly fixed invader.Draw(spriteBatch) section.

Comment: Dude, you've missed out the `invaders[6]` in your initialization code! :P

Comment: he is doing `foreach` loop, not `for` loop... also `invaders = new Animation[13];` is really bad code. add invaders to array dinamicaly.

Comment: Ah so i am thanks for that visual :) Hmm still coming up that error, Davor, I'm a newby just starting C# & XNA so forgive me if my code is poor.

Comment: @MarcBrooks Where do you call `LoadContent` ? I can't see it in the code you've posted - are you sure it gets called before you try drawing the invaders? If not then the items of the array will still be `null` and throw the exception when you try to call `Draw`.

Comment: @VisualMelon The loadcontent of the space is invaders is under the "// Array of space invaders, if it helps I'll post up the full code of the game1 file and see if that helps

Comment: Sorry man, I'm not familiar with XNA, didn't realise it was an override being called by MS' code.  Is the issue still a null reference exception on this line `invader.Draw(spriteBatch);` ? We should probably move over to SO chat to continue this discussion if you have time now as we are just filling the page with comments at the moment.

Comment: Yeah I'm fine with that. Which Chatroom or you set up 1?

Comment: VisualMelon, it seems I don't have enough rep to talk in chat... need 14 mroe which is a pain

Comment: @MarcBrooks Ah, that's a pain - is the error still the same one on the `invader.Draw(spriteBatch)` line? If so, it means that one or more of your Animations isn't being initialized - it's worth putting a breakpoint in just before the line and stepping through to see exactly what happens when it crashes.

Comment: Yeah the error is still the same 1 on the  `invader.Draw(spriteBatch)`, will check with breakpoint & see what's going on.

Comment: Okay so i put a breakpoint around by my invader.Draw(spriteBatch) and got an error coming from my button class in which it show the `public void Draw(SpriteBatch spritebatch) { spritebatch.Draw(texture, rectangle, colour);}` saying:  "InvalidOperationException was unhandled: Begin must be called successfully before a Draw can be called." I'll add in the Button.Cs as well

Comment: I'm afraid I'm all out ideas, and running out of time - if you've still not solved the problems by tomorrow then feel free to comment back and maybe you can give me a copy of your code to look it, I'm not versed in XNA but I can't see any reason this should fail were it is. Sorry I can't be more help right now, hope you figure it out. VM

Comment: Are you still getting the NullReferenceException? If so, put a breakpoint on the `foreach` line just before it, and inspect the contents of the `invaders` array. Make sure that it doesn't contain a single `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

C# has wonderful library of collection classes to replace list. I highly discourage to use Array as it is not flexible enough. If you are writing code specifically for low end hardware and knowing in and out of code and managing every bit of it than and only then go for array.

But I like the way you structured classes. It is pretty good. Now, if you have list then you can add any number of class at any moment of time. You don't have to decide above time how to do that.

Now, that class has collection of Rectangles which gives the position of sprite in your sprite collection, then you just need to use the in draw method with your animation logic. Which you already have.

And one more thing, There is no need to add

```
Content.Load<Texture2D>("SpaceInvaderbefore")
```

multiple time. Instead store it to variable and use it.

With this here is the line of two wonderful article. [1](http://forum.ragezone.com/f578/c-xna-custom-animated-sprite-661938/) and [2](http://www.freewebs.com/campelmxna/Articles/XnaAdvancedAnimation.htm). Which provide details about how to do animation with XNA. 
And there is must have course of [Plural Sight](http://www.pluralsight.com/) for game development. You can also try that.

I hope my answer helps you. please let me know if any further details required.